# Copy Data from one sheet and replace in another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take data in a master sheet to update  data in a separate sheet. I currently have it to search for criteria in the A column and if it matches to paste it in the sheet with the same name as the criteria. However it does not replace the information or start from the top. I would like it to clear out data that is no longer in the master sheet and start in the second Row on the paste sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HHC()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim matchRow As Long

With Worksheets(1)    
    For Each Cell In .Range("H:H")
        If Cell.Value = "HHC" Then
            matchRow = .Cell.Row
            .Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
            .Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
            Selection.Copy        
            Worksheets(4).Select
            Worksheets(4).Rows(matchRow).Select
            Worksheets(4).Paste
            .Select
        End If
    Next        
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are always pasting to the fourth sheet. You can incidentally avoid Selecting.

Comment: Also if I were you I wouldn't loop through a million cells.

Comment: As @SJR said, you don't want to be looping through a million rows.  Your current .Range("H:H") is 1,048,576 rows.  You would be advised to use `LastRow = sht.Range("H1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`  or similar to restrict your range to only used cells.

Answer (score 0):

For running this code remove dot from below  code.

```
matchRow = Cell.Row
```

Instead of

```
matchRow = .Cell.Row
```